# Can a Delayed Job be debugged after it's been queued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I'm using Rails 4.2, Active Job and Delayed Job to deliver emails to new users.

If I made a coding error in the mailer (say an misspelled variable for example), and ActiveJob::DelayedJob raised an exception, is there any way to fix the coding error, but have that same job re-run with the new fixed code?

Perhaps I'm doing this wrong, but I'm wondering what the purpose is of having Delayed Job retry broken code again and again if it can't be fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart your delayed job workers as soon as you have made changes to the buggy code so that changes may take effect.

If you want to run a specific job manually, you can do that by running a new instance of rails console and executing following piece of code

`Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.find(1)) # replace 1 with the job number.`

Comment: So if I 1) fix the code, then 2) restart the delayed Job workers, the old jobs will attempt to run again but with the new fixed code? Is this something that I should do every time I deploy bug fixes?

Comment: yes, this is just like you reload the rails environment on production e.g. using touch command with passenger to restart passenger server instances